# How to search through a file to find integers

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, vector

I apologize in advance if this has already been covered, but I've been looking for the past couple of hours and i'm being driven to the point of insanity.

I have to basically read in an input file that could have integers anywhere in the file.

sample input:

> word word word word 5 word word 7 word word word word word 8 word word word word. word word word word word word 67. word 9

I need to get only the integers, then put said integers in a vector. I tried just reading it in a character at a time, then converting it to a type int, but that doesn't really work. I tried reading it in via string, then converting it to a integer, but that doesn't work either. The numbers could be in any place within the file. I hope this makes sense, but any help would be appreciated.

I am using Visual Studios if it matters. I'm also programming in c++.

Comment: You'll have to read the whole input, split it by the space to an array of words, then clean the words (remove dots and commas etc.), then test the word is integer and pick it up if it is. have you tried that?! if you did and it didn't work tell us why

Comment: I have not. Give me some time to try and implement it. Thank you thought!

Comment: Sounds homework to me.

Answer (score 2):

This program looks for integers on stdin (you can use another istream if you like) and prints them, one per line.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::istream& input = std::cin;
    intmax_t value;
    while (!input.eof()) {
        if (input >> value) {
            std::cout << value << '\n';
        } else { // not an integer, ignore up to next space                                                             
            input.clear();
            input.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ' ');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [`<regex>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator):

```
const std::string input{"word word word word 5 word word 7 word word word word word 8 word word word word. word word word word word word 67. word 9"};

std::regex numbers_pattern(R"((\b\d+()\b))");

for (std::sregex_token_iterator begin(input.begin(), input.end(),
     numbers_pattern, 1), end; begin != end; ++begin)
{
    std::cout << *begin << '\n';
}
```

With this regex iterator you can look for numbers in the string and capture them as text, then you transform the text into number with the approach you like the most.

Take a look to the <kbd>[Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Ckbytkoi8mM9dXiC)</kbd>.

To use it with a file you should replace the `std::string input` with a file stream.